# An error in SQL syntax

Tags: php

The SQL statement is as follows:

```
$sql = "
INSERT INTO usertable
(
    userid,,
    name,
    username,
    password,
    typeofuser,
    dateofaddition,
    createdby,
    status
)
VALUES (
     $userid,
    '$empname',
    '$username',
    '$password',
    '$usertype',
    '$doa',
    '$createdby',
    '$radiobt'
)
";
```

Comment: and what's the error?

Comment: You have extra `,` after `userid`

Comment: Could not enter data: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''','','','','','','')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the comma from after userid and correctly include your variables

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO usertable
    (
        userid,
        name,
        username,
        password,
        typeofuser,
        dateofaddition,
        createdby,
        status
    )
VALUES
    (
        ".$userid.",
        ".$empname.",
        ".$username.",
        ".$password.",
        ".$usertype.",
        ".$doa.",
        ".$createdby.",
        ".$radiobt."
    )";
```

Make sure you prepare this statement before getting it into the DB! (more info: [Prepared statement (Wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement))

Comment: Could not enter data: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''','','','','','','')'

Comment: updated, looks like your variables weren't in there correctly.

Comment: Its correct, I have checked in phpMyadmin,its working fine there

Answer (score 0):

There is a double ,, after userid.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO usertable(userid,name,username,password,typeofuser,dateofaddition,createdby,status) VALUES ($userid,'$empname','$username','$password','$usertype','$doa','$createdby','$radiobt')"
```

Comment: $sql = "INSERT INTO usertable(userid,name,username,password,typeofuser,dateofaddition,createdby,status) VALUES ($userid,'$empname','$username','$password','$usertype','$doa','$createdby','$radiobt')";

Comment: Still getting an error: Could not enter data: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''','','','','','','')

Comment: The user id field was auto incremented.So it returned an error.
Thanks for all your suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Let us take things step by step:

1. Field names in the query match the field name in the table (they should exactly be the same even the case should match).
2. What and from where are the values for the varaibles getting generated?
3. Do the values correspond to the datatype of the fields in the table? 
   For eg. If there is a variable which expects to receive integer as values and it is made to store strings or characters, mysql is bound to give an error message.

Check for these and let me know.